# Is filter the right place to handle service calls based on header values in Spring?

Tags: spring-boot

Looking to make a service call based on a header value.
I can see two options:
1) Do it from the controller which is mainly used for a different service.
2) Add a filter which will do this by reading the request context.

Want to know what's the best way to handle this in a Spring application.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on your requirements.

***Controller:***

If you have to make service calls for preparing the response of a ***specific*** controller. For example, you have a controller say:
/employee
fand or preparing the response of this endpoint you need to call say staff service.
In this case, it's better to handle such calls in controllers.

***Filter:***

If you want to intercept ***each*** request and perform some operation on the request before sending it to the controller or before sending the response to the client.

*A use case here can be checking the roles of the user by intercepting all requests.*

As we know by using the filter, we can perform two operations at two instances −
Before sending the request to the controller
Before sending a response to the client.

In this case, OncePerRequestFilter is quite useful from the spring web module. 
Quoting the documentation :

> Filter base class that aims to guarantee a single execution per request dispatch, on any servlet container.